# How can I redirect a subdomain without needing to use a port, on a home server?

Tags: port, redirection, url, nginx

Current setup at home:

- Router OS - openWRT
- Router remote access - port 80
- Server OS - Arch Linux
- Web server - nginx
- Server web server access - port 81 (port redirection done in router)
- Modem IP address - dynamic
- Domain owned - example.com (as an example)

I have a domain name example.com. I have the following host records created:

- An "A record" router1 that always points to my dynamic IP
- CNAMEs for my subdomains pointing towards the above "A record"

My home server serves a few sites; each has a specific (different and distinct) location on the server for its files. I use the "server_name" attribute in nginx, to point to the various subdomains.

My problem: currently to access one of my sites, I have to type http://site1.example.com:81. I want to be able to omit the port, and type http://site.example.com. I thought URL Redirection is what was needed, but I am told by my domain name hoster that I cannot simultaneously have a CNAME and an URL Redirection.

How can I solve my above problem? Is this something that I can only somehow get openWRT to solve, or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup, this is not possible.

The reason is that your router has remote access set to port 80.

In order to alter this, you'll have to change your router's remote access port from 80 to something else, eg: 8080 or 81.

Then setup port forwarding from external port 80 to internal port 80/81 (the internal ip address of your webserver with the port you configured it for).

Then on your DNS set an A or CNAME record for the subdomain and make it point to your external ip address.

Comment: Thanks for this. So, if someone has multiple web servers behind the same router, there is no way to avoid having to use ports? One would be fine as per your directions, but for every other webserver I would be forced to use ports in the addresses?

I was hoping that openWRT would have had something to help facilitate this.

Comment: Actually, thinking about that, I guess the "primary" web server could use a reverse proxy to help with multiple web servers.

Comment: Your port forwarding rules can also possibly provide port translations

Comment: When people have multiple webservers behind the same router, they usually have multiple public ip's as well. They do not route based on ports, but based on public ip's.